# "Was not declared in this scope" error struct definition. c++

Tags: c++, header, initialization, struct

I'm thinking I have angered the "Header Guard" gods, but I don't see where.  My program is laid out as follows:
(note :this is just the relevant info on these files)

main file:

```
#include "playlist.h"
#include "playlistitem.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main (int argc, char** argv)
  //snip
  PlayList allSongs;
  //snip
```

playist.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYLIST_H
#define PLAYLIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "playlistitem.h"
#include "song.h"
#include "time.h"

struct Playlist {
std::vector<Song> songs;
Time cdTotalTime;
int totalTime;
};
```

plalist.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "playlist.h"
```

song.h:

```
#ifndef SONG_H
#define SONG_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "time.h"

struct Song {
std::string title;
std::string artist;
std::string album;
int track;
Time length;
};
```

song.cpp:

```
#include "song.h"
#include "csv.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
```

I get "Playlist was not declared in this scope" on line:

```
PlayList allSongs;
```

In my main file.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any `#endif` at the end of your headers to close the `#ifndef` guards?

Comment: Why don't you post the actual error message? You said the error message states `"Playlist was not declared in this scope"` when your actual line of code uses `PlayList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your capitalization.

`Playlist` and `PlayList` are being used.

Comment: Had similar problem... Make sure to qualify with namespaces if applicable.

Answer (score 2):

You've just got your capitalization wrong... it's declared as Playlist, used as PlayList

Answer (score 1):

clang's spell checking is helpful for this type of thing.

```
tmp.cpp:5:1: error: unknown type name 'PlayList'; did you mean 'Playlist'?
PlayList pl;
^~~~~~~~
Playlist
tmp.cpp:1:8: note: 'Playlist' declared here
struct Playlist {
       ^
1 error generated.
```